# COUNT AND MULTI GROUP BY MONTH MYSQL

Tags: mysql, eloquent

please help me, I want to display data with eloquent, before that I have to create a Raw Query to make it easier for me when I want to implement it to Eloquent.
I want to get a result like this :

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILIT5.png)

I've tried using this query, but the result is not what I want.

```
SELECT COUNT(t.pengaduan_id) jml, t.kanal_id, mpk.nama_kanal, DATE_FORMAT(t.created_at, '%M %Y') tgl
FROM tr_pengaduan AS t
LEFT JOIN ms_pengaduan_kanal mpk ON t.kanal_id = mpk.kanal_id
GROUP BY YEAR(t.created_at),MONTH(t.created_at) ORDER BY kanal_id
```

**Result of the above query :**
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7ADd.png)

**Here are the details from the table :**

**1. Table Tr_pengaduan :** [Tr_pengaduan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpThh.png)

**2. Table ms_pengaduan_kanal :** [ms_pengaduan_kanal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BinWk.png)

> **Is there a way to get the result I want with/without creating a procedure or function? I really appreciate it if you reply with Raw Query or Eloquent or both.**

---

**UPDATE :**
I tried @ProGu 's suggestion, but the result of the join is partially NULL.

```
SELECT COUNT(t.pengaduan_id) jml, t.kanal_id, mpk.nama_kanal, DATE_FORMAT(t.created_at, '%M %Y') tgl, mont.MONTH
FROM tr_pengaduan AS t
LEFT JOIN ms_pengaduan_kanal mpk ON t.kanal_id = mpk.kanal_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AS
MONTH
UNION SELECT MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())-1 AS
MONTH
UNION SELECT MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())-2 AS
MONTH
UNION SELECT MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())-3 AS
MONTH
UNION SELECT MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())-4 AS
MONTH) AS mont ON MONTH(t.created_at) = mont.MONTH
WHERE t.kanal_id = mpk.kanal_id
GROUP BY mpk.kanal_id ORDER BY kanal_id
```

Result : [Update Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Tecl.png)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "we'll do your work for you" site.
Show your effort, instead of asking for a ready solution. Show specific errors you need help with and example output that you expect.

Comment: looks like you need a kind of calendar table to join with your current query, so as to get zero count  for missing months

Comment: @Ron Sorry, I didn't mean it like that. I've tried my logic but my logic doesn't work.

Comment: You need to show your effort, and explain where your error is.. not "I tried and it does not work, please help me"..

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: @ProGu `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%M %Y')` It only shows the current month, how to get the previous 5 months?

Comment: Thanks @Ron . I'm reading it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

three parts in the query

- month5 - represent current month and previous 4 months
- t - id and names for result set
- counts - counting results for last 5 months

---

```
SELECT COALESCE(counts.jml, 0) counts, t.kanal_id, t.nama_kanal, DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL month5.months MONTH, '%M %Y') tgl
FROM (
  SELECT 0 AS months
  UNION
  SELECT 1
  UNION
  SELECT 2
  UNION
  SELECT 3
  UNION
  SELECT 4
) month5
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT t.kanal_id, MAX(mpk.nama_kanal) nama_kanal
  FROM tr_pengaduan t
  LEFT JOIN ms_pengaduan_kanal mpk ON t.kanal_id = mpk.kanal_id
  WHERE t.created_at BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY - INTERVAL 4 MONTH AND NOW()
  GROUP BY t.kanal_id
) t
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(t.pengaduan_id) jml, t.kanal_id, DATE(MAX(t.created_at)) tgl
  FROM tr_pengaduan AS t
  WHERE t.created_at BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY - INTERVAL 4 MONTH AND NOW()
  GROUP BY t.kanal_id, YEAR(t.created_at), MONTH(t.created_at) 
) counts ON LAST_DAY(counts.tgl) = LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL month5.months MONTH) AND t.kanal_id = counts.kanal_id
ORDER BY kanal_id, tgl
```